# SeleniumLibrary doesn't accept executable_path

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, acceptance-testing

I'm switching from pytest + Selenium to robotframework + SeleniumLibrary + Selenium. Despite SeleniumLibrary keyword designed to be easier in use I can't match some simple operations from vanilla Selenium to SeleniumLibrary.
For example I've searched about executable_path and trying all solutions but none of them working correctly. While with pytest I can create a webdriver like:

```
driver = Chrome(executable_path='../drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://<URL>")
```

with SeleniumLibrary none of the following variant won't work:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Suite description
Library  SeleniumLibrary
*** Variables ***
${URL}  https://<URL>
*** Test Cases ***
Login_test
  Open Browser  ${URL}  Chrome  executable_path="/path/to/driver/chromedriver"
```

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Suite description
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem
*** Variables ***
${URL}  https://<URL>
${EXECDIR}  /path/to/driver/
*** Test Cases ***
Login_test
  Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ${EXECDIR}
  Open Browser  ${URL}  Chrome
```

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Suite description
Library           SeleniumLibrary
*** Variables ***
${URL}  https://<URL>
${chromedriver}  /path/to/driver/chromedriver
*** Test Cases ***
Login_test
  Create Webdriver  Chrome  chrome  executable_path=${chromedriver}
  Go To ${URL}
```

Is there any workaround besides manually adding path to driver to PATH variable?

Comment: Your final example is the correct way to do it. What happens when you run that code?

Comment: @BryanOakley indeed, it's the only correct way to set path to chromedriver. Actually my code was with quotes:
`${chromedriver}  "/path/to/driver/chromedriver"` and when I fixed it to `${chromedriver}  /path/to/driver/chromedriver` everything has worked.

Comment: That is the problem with not posting actual code that reproduces the problem. That problem would have been obvious if the code you posted was an accurate representation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

My original code was with quotes: `${chromedriver} "/path/to/driver/chromedriver"` and when I fixed it to `${chromedriver} /path/to/driver/chromedriver` everything has worked. So the only correct way for the moment is the last option from the original post:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Suite description
Library           SeleniumLibrary
*** Variables ***
${URL}  https://<URL>
${chromedriver}  /path/to/driver/chromedriver
*** Test Cases ***
Login_test
  Create Webdriver  Chrome  chrome  executable_path=${chromedriver}
  Go To ${URL}
```